# Handshake failed when i try to contact web page from Flutter Mobile App

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, flutter-web, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to open a link from my flutter mobile app, but I'm getting a handshake problem.

I used the following library: ***url_launcher: ^6.1.5***

The implemented code is the following, which should open the web page when the button is clicked:

```
Widget _buildButtonLinks() {
return ElevatedButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    var url = 'https://www.google.com/';
    if (await canLaunchUrlString(url)) {
      await launchUrlString(url); //forceWebView is true now
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
  },
  child: Icon(
    Icons.link,
    color: Colors.black,
    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.09114,
  ),
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      primary: Color.fromRGBO(213, 218, 227, 1.0),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
        // <-- Radius
      ),
      minimumSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8854,
          MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.0629)),
);}
```

When I click the button the page does not load and remains blank, and the following message appears in the debug console:

> E/chromium(18929): [ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(996)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200

How can I make it work?

Comment: Have you added internet permission in manifest file?

Comment: Yes, i add the internet permission in manifest, but i have the same problem.

Comment: Can you please tell me in which device are you testing and running

Comment: i'm using an Android ONEPLUS device.

Comment: Is it emulator?

Comment: no, it is a real device connect with USB.